# Add popup window in wordpress (add_records.php)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to add pop up window when users click on it. Everything works fine in the following code except resizing the window. I appreciate any help or input. Firstly, 
In your child theme's folder create another folder called js (unless your theme already has a js folder) and within that folder create a new file called popup.js Paste into that file the following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $('.popup').click(function() {
     var NWin = window.open($(this).prop('href'), '', 'scrollbars=1,height=400,width=400');
     if (window.focus)
     {
       NWin.focus();
     }
     return false;
    });
});
```

Secondly, in your child theme's functions.php add the following:

```
//* Register and Enqueue scripts for popup
function cc_popup_script() {
    wp_register_script( 'popup', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/popup.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', false );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'popup' );
 }

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'cc_popup_script');
```

Once you have added the code above, you can now use this in your page/post content by attaching a class of 'popup' to any link you want to open in a popup. For example

```
<a href="add_records.php?Add New" class="popup">popup example page</a>
```

Please help

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add the resizable option.  Just change this line:

```
var NWin = window.open($(this).prop('href'), '', 'scrollbars=1,height=400,width=400');
```

to this:

```
    var NWin = window.open($(this).prop('href'), '', 'scrollbars=1,height=400,width=400,resizable=1');
```